# Injecting JSP from Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC web app that uses JSP for the View technology. In the controller I am injecting values into the `ModelAndView` object that will then be used (with the respective JSP) to help construct the final HTML to return to the client-side.

The controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView widgets(@Model Fruit fruit, @RequestParam("texture") String texture) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    // The name of the JSP to inject and return.
    max.setViewName("widgets/AllWidgets");

    int buzz = calculateBuzzByTexture(texture);

    mav.addObject("fruitType", fruit.getType());
    mav.addObject("buzz", buzz);

    return mav;
}
```

This controller (which handles `/widgets.html` requests) does some lookups and returns the injected `AllWidgets.jsp` page. In that JSP page, I need to get access to both the `fruitType` and `buzz` variables (inside both HTML and JS), but not sure how I can do this. For instance, assuming `fruitType` is a String (and `buzz` is an `int`), how would I print them in both HTML and JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    alert("Buzz is " + buzz);
</script>

<div>
    <h2>The type of fruit is ??? fruitType ???</h2>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring controller stores the view objects in the page context, and they are accessed using EL:

```
<div>
    <h2>The type of fruit is ${fruitType}</h2>
</div>
```

This is described in the Oracle [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html), and also in the introductory [Spring MVC tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/).

Comment: Thanks @parsifal (+1) - I *assume* the same holds true inside Javascript? Thanks again!