# Java @Model Annotation, which library do I import to use it?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, model, annotations

At this URL: [Injecting JSP from Spring MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976208/injecting-jsp-from-spring-mvc-controller)

They have the following snippet of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView widgets(@Model Fruit fruit, @RequestParam("texture") String texture)
```

My question, the @Model annotation, what library needs to be imported to make use of it?

Thank you in advance,
Wes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
```

Replace the `@Model` to`@ModelAttribute Fruit fuit` like grid answered.

And import `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;`

Take a look here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Cesar: seeing this too from searching on google, this is the one I need to use.  I include the import but when putting the @Model annotation in a method similar to the code snippet in my original post it says the following: "Model is not an annotation type".  Know why?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a typo of @ModelAttribute.

@Model is a class level annotation of J2EE 6 CDI